# SQL and Python - using a variable in an SQL statement

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlite

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('troubleshooting.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
user = input("hello")
for row in cur.execute('SELECT user FROM problems WHERE user = %s'):
    print(row)
```

My problem here is that the variable 'user' is only being read as text and not changing occurring to what I name it (user = input("hello")). How do I change it so it does read it as a variable (please keep it simple, I am a beginner when it comes to programming). 
Thanks for helping out :)

Comment: `'SELECT user FROM problems WHERE user = %s' % user` should do the trick!

Comment: for row in cur.execute('SELECT user FROM problems WHERE user = %s' % user):
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: user

Comment: It doesn't look like it has worked, I preferably want it to search for a column named screen

Comment: It still is searching for 'user'

Comment: Note: User is a reserved word in SQL. I would recommend not using it as a column name and if you're querying a table with user as a column, put it in square brackets (e.g. `SELECT [user]... WHERE [user] =`, not `user`).

Comment: The problem is that i don't want the program to recognize the 'user' as text, what I actually want it to do is run user as "screen". I have tried to change the variable user but it appears that is not the problem. Also "screen is definitely a table due to my previous tests where i changed user to "screen"

Comment: Sorted it, just changed the code to something like this "u = input("hello")
for row in cur.execute("SELECT "+u+" FROM problems"):
    print(row)"